# matrix and vector derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

Suppose $~W~$ is an $~n \times n~$ matrix and $~x$,$~y~$ are $~n \times 1~$ vectors. Then define function $~f~$ as following:

\begin{equation}
f=\left\|W\left(x-y\right)\right\|^{2}
\end{equation}
The question is what are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: idk, you tell me man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chain rule and verify the following facts:

For Euclidean vector norm $\| \cdot \| : \mathbb{R^{n}} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\frac{d \| \cdot \|}{d \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|x\|} ;
$$

For $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(t) := t^2$ the derivative is:
$$
\frac{d f(t) }{dt} = 
\frac{d t^2 }{dt} = 2t;
$$

For  $g:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^n}$, $~g(\mathbf{x}) := \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$:

$$
\frac{d g(\mathbf{x})  }{d\mathbf{x}} =
\frac{d \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}   }{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{W};
$$

For $h:\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}\to \mathbb{R^n}$,  $~h(\mathbf{W}) := \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$:

$$
\frac{d h(\mathbf{W})  }{d\mathbf{W}} =
\frac{d \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}   }{d\mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{x}^\top.
$$